# IE 11 - Django based views issue

Tags: html, django, internet-explorer-11, django-class-based-views

I have a Django app, and I'm using class-based views in some parts of it. When I try to access to these views on IE 11 it downloads the html instead of rendering it. I've searched the web and found this other posts talking about the same problem:
https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/74r2af/django_not_working_with_internet_explorer/ and
[Django: internet explorer download page content instead render it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47069717/django-internet-explorer-download-page-content-instead-render-it)
[IE 11 Downloads Page instead of opening it, works in Chrome and Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43078261/ie-11-downloads-page-instead-of-opening-it-works-in-chrome-and-firefox)

According to this is some rendering issue caused by a wrong definition of the context, but my view looks like this:

```
class BaseContentMixin(ActiveLoginRequiredMixin, TenantHasRolePermMixin, TenantActiveNotExpiredMixin, TenantHasPermMixin, SetDefaultTimezoneMixin):
"""
Attributes:
    content (str): content name, i.e 'training'.
    content_type (str): content type, 'shared' or 'custom'.
    permission (str): permission, i.e 'TRAININGS'.
"""
content = ''
content_type = ''
role_permission = 'SEE'
permission = ''

def get_content_class(self):
    return Util.get_content_class('{}-{}'.format(self.content, self.content_type))

def get_content_shared_class(self):
    return Util.get_content_class('{}-shared'.format(self.content))

class ContentListView(BaseContentMixin, TemplateView):

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(ContentListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['title'] = Util.get_content_title(self.content)
    context['active'] = self.content
    context['submenu_active'] = '{}_{}'.format(self.content, self.content_type)
    context['objects'] = self.get_content_class().objects.get_for_user(self.request.user)
    context['toggle_url'] = reverse('{}_{}_active_toggle'.format(self.content, self.content_type))
    context['add_url'] = reverse('{}_{}_add'.format(self.content, self.content_type), kwargs={'lang': get_language()})

    if self.content_type == 'custom':
        contents_shared = self.get_content_shared_class().objects.get_topics(self.request.user)
        context['form'] = Util.get_content_form_from_template(self.content)(contents_shared=contents_shared)
        context['add_url_from_template'] = reverse('{}_custom_add_from_template'.format(self.content), kwargs={'lang': get_language()})
    return context
```

When i print the context it gives me this:

```
{
  'add_url_from_template': u'/trainings/custom/add-from-template/es-ar/',
  'form': <TrainingCustomFromTemplateFrombound=False,
  valid=Unknown,
  fields=(trainings_template)>,
  'title': u'M\xf3dulos Interactivos',
  'add_url': u'/trainings/custom/add/es-ar/',
  'objects': <TranslationQueryset[
    <TrainingCustom: 1a1a1a1a1aa1>,
    <TrainingCustom: DoubleTest1>,
    <TrainingCustom: DoubleTest2>,
    <TrainingCustom: Nuevito>,
    <TrainingCustom: TestCampaign4>,
    <TrainingCustom: TestCampaignDOUBLETEST>,
    <TrainingCustom: TestCampaignDoubleTest1>,
    <TrainingCustom: TestCampaignTest>,
    <TrainingCustom: TestCampaignTest2>,
    <TrainingCustom: TestCampaignTest3>,
    <TrainingCustom: aversifunk>,
    <TrainingCustom: eeee>,
    <TrainingCustom: qweqweqwew>,
    <TrainingCustom: rrrr>,
    <TrainingCustom: weqwe>,
    <TrainingCustom: wqeqweqwe>
  ]>,
  'toggle_url': u'/trainings/custom/active-toggle/',
  'submenu_active': 'training_custom',
  'active': 'training',
  u'view': <trainingcustom.views.TrainingCustomListViewobjectat0x10af0b550>
}
```

It doesn't seem to be anything wrong about it, I'm kinda stuck here. I thought that if this was a TemplateView/IE11 compatibility issue i should've found some info about it.

Comment: If you comment out `get_context_data` does it still cause this issue? Or if you re-enable each context item one by one? However, nothing in the context looks wrong to me. On the other hand, where do you set `template_name`? And is the HTML in there valid? What else do you override in `ContentListView`?

Comment: IMHO, anything that doesnt work on IE (any versions) need not be fixed at all. Those stupid browsers don't want to grow up like chrome, firefox and opera did. Let them stay behind then ;-)

Comment: @malberts `get_context_data` as you see in this case, cannot be commented. Though I tried by leaving only the definition of the context with super(), and it doesn't work neither. I don't understand the "re-enable each context item" part. The HTML is valid and well defined, I've been using the template for a while now.

Comment: @RyuCoder I think it's pretty clear that not using IE isn't a choice. Why would anyone actually CHOOSE to use IE11 in 2019?

Comment: @gdrubich; thats my point also, Why would anyone actually CHOOSE to use IE11 in 2019? LOLZ

Comment: @gdrubich I mean to comment out every line in `get_context_data` and then uncomment them one by one. But I don't think that's the problem. It looks like you are subclassing that view, because your output mentions `TrainingCustomListView`.  What do you override in there? And do you set `template_name` there?

Comment: This is the class, some basic var definition:

`class TrainingCustomListView(views_mixins.ContentListView):
    template_name = 'trainingshared/training.html'
    content = 'training'
    content_type = 'custom'
    permission = 'TRAININGS'`

Comment: @gdrubich Oh, don't override `content_type`. It's used [by TemplateView](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.1/django.views.generic.base/TemplateView/) to determine the *response* content type. When you set that to `'custom'` the browser gets confused.

Comment: So in other words, rather give your own `content_type` a different name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BaseContentMixin` should not use a field called `content_type` because that will clash with the similarly named field in [`TemplateView`](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.1/django.views.generic.base/TemplateView/) which is ultimately used to set the *response*'s `Content-Type` header. When you override that to `'custom'`, you end up confusing the browser because that's not a valid content type.

Comment: Oh man, thank you so much! I never would have got it. THANK YOU.